# How use VPN in react Native with Pre shared shared key?( IPsec)

Tags: react-native, protocols, vpn, ipsec

I am using this NPM package in react native to make my own VPN
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ip-sec-vpn
In documentation clearly mentioned address, Username and password but its not mentioned how to use pre-shared key or mention it somewhere in code. Kindly help for it

Comment: https://github.com/sijav/react-native-ip-sec-vpn/issues/4

Comment: In that its still not clear, some is saying now we can't use IP SEC.. Its removed from new versions?